# Is the $\omega_1$'th element of a well ordered set the first with uncountable predecessors?

Tags: ordinals

As far as I understand the topic, ordinal numbers are defined as sets, but their "purpose" is to generalize the concept of indices beyond infinity.

So, can it be said that

1. the element at index $\omega$ is the first with (countably) infinite predecessors

and likewise,

2. the element at index $\omega_1$ is the first with uncountable predecessors?

I find (1) somewhat intuitive, but I can't think of an example that illustrates (2).

Comment: Note that such an element may or may not exist in the set; it exists iff the order type of the set is $>\omega_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. $\omega$ is the first ordinal which has infinitely many smaller ordinals; and $\omega_1$ is the first ordinal which has uncountably many smaller ordinals. Similarly $\omega_2$ is the first ordinal which has more than $\aleph_1$ smaller ordinals, and so on.

It seems to me that you're trying to visualize $\omega_1$. And that's not really possible. The reason is that however you might want to imagine $\omega_1$, it's much longer than that. And it's more than just that, it's also the fact that if you think about $\omega_1$ with any additional functions or relation symbols and you try to describe it using a first-order property of that structure, there will be some countable ordinal with the same properties under the same relations.

So it really means that $\omega_1$ is far far beyond our reach, when it comes to examples which illustrate it. It is something that is best to work with formally using the definition until you get a good intuition about it.

Comment: +1 for "it's not really possible to visualize $\omega_1$". I've tried many times to convey the sheer bigness of $\omega_1$ and words fail me. Alternatively, "the smallest ordinal humans cannot understand" is a large countable ordinal.

Comment: Mario, I like to think about $\omega_1$ as a "[Supernova ordinal](http://what-if.xkcd.com/73/)" (look at the sentence about the photo of a person with a nuke pressed against his eye). However big you think $\omega_1$ is, it's bigger than that.

Comment: So, even if you added countable many "far"s to your post, it still would not account for how far out of reach $\omega_1$ is. I can accept that. Nevertheless, is there an example for an element of a well ordered set that provably has uncountably many, but not a single more, predecessors, that is understandable for a mathematically inclined layperson?

Comment: @Cephalopod: Not in an interesting way. Namely, what sets can you even describe which are well-ordered and uncountable, that a working mathematician would understand? Essentially, just $\omega_1+1$ (which is the all the countable ordinals, and then $\omega_1$ on top of them). The fact that you can find an injection from $\omega_1$ into the reals already require the axiom of choice, so it's not quite tangible.